# Preserve unicode of emojis in python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm dealing with emojis Unicode and wanna save images with its corresponding Unicode like `1F636_200D_1F32B_FE0F` for https://emojipedia.org/face-in-clouds/.

But for https://emojipedia.org/keycap-digit-one/ the files end up `1_FE0F_20E3` and I need them to be `0031_FE0F_20E3` is there a way to tell the encoder to not parse the `1`?

```py
>>> '1️⃣'.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')
'1\\ufe0f\\u20e3'
```

Comment: 1️⃣ is encoded as `1 U+FE0F U+20E3`. U+FE0F is the [variant selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) that affects the previous character, saying that it's not a normal `1` but an emoji. If you don't have `1` when how can it have any effect?

Comment: @phuclv the original key is not getting affected so it won't affect the emoji. it's just for naming convention. The same thing happens with other keycaps emoji like #️⃣ I just want them as unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unicode_escape` codec displays the ASCII characters as characters, and only non-ASCII characters as escape codes.  If you want all to be escape codes, you have to format yourself:

```py
>>> ''.join([f'\\u{ord(c):04x}' if ord(c) < 0x10000 else f'\\U{ord(c):08x}' for c in '‍️'])
'\\U0001f636\\u200d\\U0001f32b\\ufe0f'
>>> ''.join([f'\\u{ord(c):04x}' if ord(c) < 0x10000 else f'\\U{ord(c):08x}' for c in '1️⃣'])
'\\u0031\\ufe0f\\u20e3'
```

Or maybe you want this format?

```py
>>> '_'.join([f'{ord(c):04X}' for c in '1️⃣'])
'0031_FE0F_20E3'
>>> '_'.join([f'{ord(c):04X}' for c in '‍️'])
'1F636_200D_1F32B_FE0F'
```